# Find the Taylor polynomial of degree 4 for cos(x), for x near 0

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am self studying calculus and I need help solving a Taylor Series problem.

**1a) Find the Taylor polynomial of degree 4 for cos(x), for x near 0:**

I think the answer would be:

1-(x^2/2!)+(x^4/4!)-(x^6/6!)+(x^8/8!)

Not entirely sure though.

1b) **Approximate cos(x) with P{4}(x) to simplify the ratio: (1/cos(x)) /x**

I am unsure how to approach and solve this part of the problem.

1c)**Using this, conclude the limit as x goes to infinity**

**(1/cos(x)) /x**

I believe the answer to this would be 0. It is an identity in the book.

Overall, I am not sure if I am going in the right direction with this. Some help and guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1a)  Your proposed Taylor polynomial has degree 8.  1b)  Replace "$\cos x$" with your Taylor polynomial and simplify.  1c)  What limit?  I see no "as $x$ goes to" here.  Limit at zero?  Limit at infinity?  (It's certainly not going to zero at zero.)

Comment: Just edited! as x goes to infinity

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's Formula is given by
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ where $a$ is where $f^{(n)}$ is evaluated at.

For 1a), you need to calculate this sum up to $n=4$, not $n=8$.  That is $\sum_{n=0}^4\dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n.$  This will be $P_4[x].$

For 1b), you know from 1a) that you can approximate $\cos(x)$ with $P_4[x].$  Then, you will have $\dfrac{1}{x\cos(x)}\approx\dfrac{1}{xP_4[x]}.$

For 1c),  then all you need to do is take $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{xP_4[x]}.$  **Hint** You can simplify it to end up with something of the form $\dfrac{c}{P[x]},$ where $c$ is a constant.  Since $P[x]$ grows without bound, then you will end up with a constant divided by an increasingly large number.  Therefore, the result will become increasingly small. i.e, we will get $0$ in the limit.